# Text Block Not Aligning

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following Textblock and I can't seem to get the text to align:

```
TextBlock headerBlock;
Canvas headerContainer;

public setLayout()
{
   headerContainer= new Canvas();
   headerContainer.Background = new Brushes.Black;

   headerBlock= new TextBlock();
   headerBlock.FontSize = 10;
   headerBlock.Text = "This must be centered";
   headerBlock.TextAlignment = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center;
   headerBlock.Foreground = Brushes.White;
   headerBlock.Padding = new System.Windows.Thickness(20);


   headerContainer.Children.Add(headerBlock);

}
```

For some reason, the `TextAlignment` does not align the text. Is there something else I can add to force the `headerBlock` text to align center?

Comment: You can use `VerticalAlignment=Center` in your `XAML`.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is due to the **Canvas**.

=> Canvas are made to organize elements according to pixel positions.
Replace your Canvas by a **Grid** and it will work.

You will also have to write what zambonee suggested:

`TextAlignment` will align text inside the control.
`HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` will align the control inside its container.

=> Play with both to obtain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The TextBlock is not expanding to fill its parent, and is probably jammed into its parent's top-left corner. Try this

```
headerBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center; //or Stretch with TextAlignment = Center
headerBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center; //or Stretch
```

Comment: Ahh I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I added 1 more line to my code, the headerContainer ads the header block, thought I'm not sure if it would affect alignment

Comment: A Canvas ignores the alignment properties of its child elements.