# TextBox not Wrapping

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a project in .Net and I can't seem to get the text within the textblock to wrap.

```
        titleBlock = new TextBlock();
        titleBlock.FontSize = 30;
        titleBlock.TextWrapping = System.Windows.TextWrapping.Wrap;
        titleBlock.Text = "jkhkjhkjh kjhkjhkjhkjhk jhkjh kjh kjh kjh kjh kjh kjh jkh k";
        titleBlock.Padding = new System.Windows.Thickness(20);
        titleBlock.Foreground = Brushes.White;
        titleLabel.Content = titleBlock;
        titleLabel.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        titleLabel.VerticalContentAlignment =System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
        titleLabel.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(20, 30, 20, 20);

        canvas.Children.Add(titleLabel);
```

Currently the text is centered. However, I can't seem to get the text to wrap. If I have too much text, it just goes off screen instead of fit in the screen.

Comment: Your title and description don't match. Is it `TextBox` or `TextBlock`?

Comment: And is it WPF or WinForms?

Comment: @Sach I think this is WPF

Comment: Based on [the previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719125/text-block-not-aligning) question, it is WPF.

Comment: @mjwills sorry I'm new to C#, .net, but I'm pretty sure from the documentation I read it's WPF

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `canvas` variable is a `Canvas` then your problem is that you are using a `Canvas` and have not specified a `Width` or `MaxWidth` for your text block. A `Canvas` does not force any kind of size restrains on its children; it will allow them to grow without bounds even beyond its own borders. Text wrapping will only occur once the `TextBlock` has reached its maximum allowed width. Since the `Canvas` allows infinite width that will never happen. A `Canvas` is not the best panel to use in the vast majority of situations. Take a look at the `StackPanel` or `Grid` panels.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jason Boyd said, "A `Canvas` does not force any kind of size restrains on its children". You should specify a `Width` value to the `textblock`.

```
var labelHorMargin = titleLabel.Margin.Left + titleLabel.Margin.Right;
var blockHorMargin = titleBlock.Margin.Left + titleBlock.Margin.Right;

titleBlock.Width = canvas.Width - labelHorMargin  - blockHorMargin;
```